# Enviar um objeto usando Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

Estou com o seguinte problema: preciso enviar um objeto para o meu web-service, porém, não é viável usar JSONStringer, pois a minha classe possui muitos campos. Qual seria a melhor forma de resolver este problema? Usei o seguinte método, porém não funcionou (retorna que meu objeto é nulo), segue o código:

```
 public String postPedido( Pedido pedido) 
 {
        int statusCode = 400;
        try 
        {

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SVC_URL );
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

           Gson gson = new Gson();

           String json = gson.toJson(pedido, Pedido.class);
           StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);


           request.setEntity(entity);

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        } 

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return String.valueOf(statusCode);
    }
```

Segue a assinatura do método do Web Service:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "PostPedido",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool PostPedido(Pedido pedido);
```

E o método é este:

```
public bool PostPedido(Pedido pedido)
    {
        var teste = new StringBuilder();
        bool result = false;
        if (pedido != null)
        {
            teste.AppendLine(String.Format("Numero do pedido {0}", pedido.NumeroOrcamento));
            teste.AppendLine(String.Format("Total Pedido {0}", pedido.TotalPedido));
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            teste.AppendLine("pedido vazio");
            result = false;
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\teste.txt", teste.ToString());

        return result;
    }
```

PS: Por enquanto, este método é apenas para teste.

Comment: Qual exatamente é o seu objeto nulo que você se refere? A string `json`? O `entity`? Caso for este segundo, experimente informar o *charset* no segundo parâmetro.

Comment: O objeto é reconhecido como nulo pelo Web-service.

Comment: Fabio, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Não parece haver nada de errado com seu código, mas pode ser um problema ou incompatibilidade com o web service. O ideal seria recuperar o log bruto de como a requisição chega no servidor para determinar se ela está chegando exatamente no formato esperado. Tem como postar o método usado no web service?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, acrescentando o método usado no Web Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a propriedade BodyStyle do atributo WebInvoke do método PostPedido no contrato para:

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse
```